# Вывести строку один раз

Tags: c#

Простой `цикл от 0 до 100` и прописана строка типа `strokaa`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("strokaa");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

но надо, чтобы эта строка выводилась только один раз, как решить ?
код выводить 100 раз подряд `strokaa` а надо лишь один раз
вместо

```
strokaa
strokaa
strokaa
strokaa
...
strokaa
```

просто

```
strokaa
```

этот метод конечно гут, но он не годится(

```
if (i==0)
          Console.WriteLine("strokaa");
```

Comment: `if(!i)` добавить?

Comment: @teran а куда добавить ?

Comment: ну уж помозгуйте сами то? куда тут можно добавить, если у вас есть цикл и команда строка вывода, а вам надо вставить туда условие.

Comment: я хз.............

Comment: поставьте `//` перед `for`

Comment: Хотел поставить вопросу минус, но после "я хз..." рука не поднимается.

Comment: Зачем вам нужен цикл? Там еще что-то вычисляется? Если нет, уберите его.

Comment: strokaa - это по-фински?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka на данный момент все равно

Comment: интрига нарастает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так.

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("strokaa");
            break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Какова конечная цель ? Зачем вам цикл ?

Comment: Поверьте, надо:-)

Comment: @Doe хорошо Верю =)

Comment: вот если бы мой вопрос плюсануть 3 раза, я бы ваш ответ плюсанул...сайт пишет, что низя мне((Ваши голоса начнут влиять на рейтинг сообщений, как только ваша репутация превысит порог в 15 баллов.)

Comment: @Doe Ну надеюсь решение помогло )

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
              Console.WriteLine("strokaa");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Может так?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("strokaa");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: я знаю, так можно прописать, но это мне не годится(

Comment: @Doe дак сформулируете может ваши требования, если очевидный вариант вам не годится?

Comment: @teran переформулировал вопрос.

Comment: да, это решение не годится, потому что в нем не хватает команды `break;`

Comment: Мне хочется вспомнить анекдот, но нельзя оскорблять автора. ((

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka - я тоже вспомнил анекдот, но, возможно, другой